# glsl - iOS - Discard keyword

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, glsl, cocos2d-x, fragment-shader

In official docs Apple suggests to use `discard` as soon as possible in fragment shaders.

But searching through the forums of some game engines I found out that many people think that discard is very very slow in fragment shaders.

What whould be the best practice in iOS fragment shaders:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0);
```

or

```
discard;
```

?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to profile both approaches, and use the one that gives you the best performance.

The reason that the discard keyword can slow down the rendering, is that it disables early depth culling.

There is a really good answer on the performance of the discard keyword in this link: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/40301/do-i-lose-gain-performance-for-discarding-pixels-even-if-i-dont-use-depth-testi